# using the ... argument inline

Tags: r

I have the following function

```
sjbDo <- function(operation, x, statelist, Spos, isFuture = FALSE) {

  # run the operation on x
  xvec <- operation(x);

  # and so on

}
```

and I could call it like this:

```
A <- sjbDo( function(x) {x}, statelist$A, statelist, 1)
```

However, I want to modify sjbDo so that the inline function can take additional arguments. Something like:

```
kTheta <- sjbDo( function(x, b) {x^b}, statelist$K, statelist, 1, FALSE, b=theta.k)
```

I tried

```
sjbDo <- function(operation, x, statelist, Spos, isFuture = FALSE, ...) {

  # run the operation on x
  xvec <- operation(x,...);
```

But this doesn't seem to work. How can I get this to work?

Comment: operation <- function(x,...) {x^...[[1]]}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more canonical solution would look like:

```
operation <- function(x, ...) {
    dots <- list(...)
    x^dots[[1]]
}
```

but if you know enough to say that the argument you want is the first argument passed as `...` then you should make that an argument. Because your code (and mine) won't work when called like this for example:

```
> operation(1:10, foo = "bar", b = 2)
Error in x^dots[[1]] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

If you grab `...` as I have above, then you can pull out the argument you want if it is named:

```
operation <- function(x, ...) {
    dots <- list(...)
    want <- which(names(dots) == "b")
    stopifnot(length(want) > 0)
    b <- dots[[want]]
    x^b
}
```

Which works like this:

```
> operation(1:10, foo = "bar", b = 2)
 [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

but still fails if `b` is not a named argument:

```
> operation(1:10, foo = "bar", 2)
Error: length(want) > 0 is not TRUE
```

So what you have come up with might work in the one use case you present, but it isn't a more general strategy for doing what you want to do. What should `operation` do if there are no extra arguments passed in? Your code *assumes* there are other arguments and as such are no longer optional - which is what you indicated they were. If `b` should take some other default value if non is supplied, then the whole thing becomes easier:

```
operation <- function(x, b = 1) {
    x^b
}

sjbDo <- function(FUN, x, ...) {
    ## function matching
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    # run the operation on x
    xvec <- FUN(x, ...)
    xvec
}
```

Which gives:

```
> sjbDo(operation, 1:10)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> sjbDo(operation, 1:10, b = 2)
 [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
> sjbDo("operation", 1:10, b = 2)
 [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

The latter works because of the use of `match.fun`.

The point of the above is that I don't think you want `operation()` to have a `...` argument because I don't see how such code could possibly work. What I think you want is a way to write the outer function call `sjbDo()` to have a few named arguments and pass any other arguments on to the function you want to call within `sjbDo()`, which I call here `FUN` and you called `operation`.

In other words, what I think you want is a wrapper (`sjbDo()`) that can call a given function (supplied as argument `FUN`) with argument `x`, plus any other arguments that `FUN` requires, without having to think of all the possible arguments `FUN` will require?

Comment: thank you. This really helps a lot and will improve my future R.

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, I figured it out

operation <- function(x,...) {x^...[[1]]}

Thanks anyway.